# Having issues upgrading PHP 5.3.3 to 5.5

Tags: php, apache, centos

Apache version: `2.2.15`

PHP (old): `5.3.3`

I'm trying to upgrade to PHP `5.5` because some features that I'm using do not work with my website that I'm making. I've tried https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/, but to no avail. It says PHP `5.5.24` in `"php -v"`, but when I use the `phpinfo()` function, it still says I'm on PHP `5.3`. What could be the issue here?

I've made sure that the PHP module for Apache is loaded, so that can't possibly be the issue (or can it?).

It also seems as though the attempted upgrade broke my XenForo installation, as well. I can figure out how to fix this on my own, but I need to figure out how to fix PHP first.

My OS is CentOS 6 (latest version). Anyone know any way to install PHP 5 or fix this issue that I am having? Thanks.

Comment: First, did you _really_ restart the http server? Or the fastcgi/fcgi server if you are using that? Then, maybe there are _two_ versions installed now? Keep in mind that cli and http module may very well use separate executables.

Comment: Used "service httpd restart" after updating php. Maybe I do have two versions.

Sure looks like it's fine:

php.x86_64; v5.5.24-1.el6.remi
php-cli.x86_64; v5.5.24-1.el6.remi
php-common.x86_64; v5.5.24-1.el6.remi
php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64; v1.3.7-1.el6.remi.5.5
php-pecl-zip.x86_64; v1.12.5-1.el6.remi.5.5

Comment: phpinfo should tell you which module it uses, so the path to the library. Compare it to the contents listed for the packages you mentioned.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you are not actually looking at a cached version, when you access phpinfo() via a browser. Make a deep reload, wipe the browsers cache and check in the http servers log files.

Comment: And a last thing, since you did not answer to it in your comment: if you are using a standalone fastcgi/fcgi server beside the http server (a common setup), then restarting the http server does _not_ restart php. In such case you have to restart that standalone cgi server. So check how your system runs php inside the http server.

Comment: I am not sure how to use FastCGI, and I'm not sure if FastCGI is installed. Also, I installed the "php55" package from yum, and it is not recognizing PHP (files are not doing their job, they're outputting as text), and there is no Apache module in the modules folder. Is there any other information that can help solve this, and if so, how can I do it? Just trying to upgrade here...have uninstalled PHP almost 5 times now, and the only version that works is 5.3.3.

Comment: Okay, figured it out. Just uninstalled HTTPD, PHPMYADMIN, and PHP and just installed it all again but instead of PHP, I installed PHP55u. Weird.

Comment: Sounds like you did not upgrade the php5 _module_. That is a separate package which probably did not get pulled by the upgrades. It is called mod_php or something. When reinstalling the httpd it probably got reinstalled too, but this time in the highest available version. Sorry, my fault, I forgot to hint at the fact that there is a separate php module for apache. But it is great that you solved things!